# Guide on how to trace memory of objects in R

Tags: r, memory, data.table, copy

While checking speed with microbenchmark seems to be straightforward, I struggle with tracking memory usage.

So to have a concrete example, say I have the following:

```
set.seed(12)

library(data.table)

dt_size <- 1e7

dt <- 
  data.table(
    'a1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T)
  )
```

Say I want to split the data: All records with "a1 == 0" should be kept as they are and all others should be aggregated and result in one respective line. So I could do:

```
dt_aggr <- 
  rbind(
    dt[a1 == '1'],
    dt[a1 != '1', lapply(.SD, sum)]
  )
```

Maybe there is a faster way, but that's not the point here.

I am wondering: What is happening here? Is R doing a copy from `dt` with the respective expression `a1 == '1'` AND a copy with the respective expression `a1 != '1'`?

Because if so I would assume that `dt` is then at least for a short period twice within the memory and then I would probably think "hm, may not be a good idea I should probably look for a solution completely within the already existing dt". If it does not make a copy than it would be fine for me, at least if there is no faster solution.

Is there a possibility to track this for someone who not deeply understands the memory allocation and wants to just try it out? What is the best way to do so?

Comment: As a hopefully helpful guide, with some tools for tracking, the [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#binding-basics) foundation chapters are very good for this. The `lobstr::obj_addr()` function could be useful for tracking in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find `bench::mark` to be helpful, e.g., demonstrating the inefficiency of the type coercion in the example:

```
bench::mark(
  dt[a1 == '1'],
  dt[a1 == 1],
  dt[a1 == 1L]
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 "dt[a1 == \"1\"]"    1.31s    1.31s     0.764   154.5MB     0   
#> 2 "dt[a1 == 1]"       1.21ms   1.36ms   660.       77.3MB     6.32
#> 3 "dt[a1 == 1L]"      1.21ms    1.3ms   743.      394.2KB     6.24
```

Coercion to a string is 3 orders of magnitude slower and uses ~4K times as much memory.

Answer (score 2):

As a brief overview which may not fully answer your question (principally it doesn't yet give you an optimisation strategy), tracing the memory locations shows that its copying a lot.

```r
set.seed(12)

library(data.table)

dt_size <- 1e3

colA <- paste0('a', 1:3)
colB <- paste0('a', 1:3)
colC <- paste0('c', 1:3)

dt <- 
  data.table(
    'a1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T)
  )
```

The object addresses for your base `dt` show the six memory locations of the six vectors making up the columns:

```r
lobstr::obj_addrs(dt)
#> [1] "0x1e28495df40" "0x1e286d9a010" "0x1e286b51010" "0x1e284662010"
#> [5] "0x1e2848f70a0" "0x1e2848f80b0"
```

When subsetting this `data.table`, R necessarily writes this new 'temporary' object to a new memory location:

```r
lobstr::obj_addrs(dt[a1 == '1'])
#> [1] "0x1e288a82df8" "0x1e288a82dc0" "0x1e288a82d88" "0x1e288a82d50"
#> [5] "0x1e288a82d18" "0x1e288a82ce0"
```

And when joining two of these together, it copies them to a further set of memory addresses:

```r
dt_aggr <- 
  rbind(
    dt[a1 == '1'],
    dt[a1 != '1', lapply(.SD, sum)]
  )

lobstr::obj_addrs(dt_aggr)
#> [1] "0x1e288b206d8" "0x1e288b20698" "0x1e288b20658" "0x1e288b20618"
#> [5] "0x1e288b205d8" "0x1e288b20598"
```

There are ways to [modify in place](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#modify-in-place), but as far as I can tell changing the length of a vector (or dataframe; via `rbind` or subsetting) will *always* copy the vector as the size of memory allocated is not constant.

### Tracking *how much* is used

One further thing to note - as I see your question is more about how much extra memory is being taken up - when subsetting using your above selectors R doesn't actually copy the *whole* data.table. `dt` doesn't itself exist twice within the memory, rather it seems to selectively read from place 1 to create new entities in place 2:

```r
library(lobstr)

dt_size <- 1e7

colA <- paste0('a', 1:3)
colB <- paste0('a', 1:3)
colC <- paste0('c', 1:3)

dt <- 
  data.table(
    'a1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T)
  )

mem_used()
#> 284.34 MB

dt[a1 == 1]
#>       a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
#>    1:  1 407 668 767 346 951
#>    2:  1 607 162 642 983 122
#>    3:  1  76 904 804 258 313
#>    4:  1 621 165  92 708 851
#>    5:  1 263 374 310 412   4
#>   ---                       
#> 9757:  1 104  50  71 982 134
#> 9758:  1 351 682 715 743 684
#> 9759:  1 820 146 536 699 577
#> 9760:  1 971 182 520 542 672
#> 9761:  1 280 424  43 356  89

mem_used()
#> 327.44 MB

dt_aggr <- 
  rbind(
    dt[a1 == 1],
    dt[a1 != 1, lapply(.SD, sum)]
  )

mem_used()
#> 332.59 MB
```